# How to draw a CardView with borders and elevation to a Canvas?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-canvas

I am using the Drag and Drop Framework. I have a `DragShadowBuilder` subclass called `MyDragShadowBuilder`, and inside the `onDrawShadow(Canvas)` method, I am trying to draw the `CardView` I pass to `MyDragShadowBuilder` like this:

`cardView.draw(canvas)`

It draws the CardView, but without the drop shadow and the rounded corners. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find a solution to this problem. I am confident there is a way to do this using only Canvas, but frankly, I don't think it's worth the effort. I wasted way too much time on this, so I ended up using a 9-patch simulating the rounded borders and the elevation. Works decently enough.